# Add konva js into existing canvas

Tags: konvajs

Is it possible to add konva js into existing canvas?
the canvas class is "custom" and it does not have an id is it possible to initiate Konva stage directly into a canvas instead of a container?

Answer (score 0):

At the current moment (`v1.1.8`) `Konva` doesn't support this a use case. You can't use `Konva` with the existing canvas element.
You can use it only with `<div>` container.

Comment: Thanks for the replay